# I cannot add items to my RecyclerView from another intent

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two intents.
Main Activity: Containing the Recycler View, showing some default items to make sure it works. An ArrayList is set to the Recycler View, which is the List containing those default items.

Second Activity: A button which will collect the data on the same page and put the data into an object, the object will be added into the Arraylist which set to the Recycler View of the Main Activity.

I made some Toast Message to confirm the object in the 2nd Activity was added to the ArrayList.

```
//My item
public item(int id, int money, String date, String category, String 
description) {
    this.id = id;
    Money = money;
    Date = date;
    Category = category;
    Description = description;
}
```

Then I created a class to control my ArrayList

```
//Building ArrayList
public Util(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Util: Start");
    if(IncomeItems==null){
        IncomeItems = new ArrayList<>();
        initIncomeItems();
    }        
}
private static void initIncomeItems() {
    Log.d(TAG, "initIncomeItems: initI");
    int Iid = 0
    int Money= 0;
    String Date = "";
    String Category= "";
    String Description = "";

     Iid++;
     IncomeItems.add(new item(Iid, 10000, "8-Jun-2019", "Salary", 
"Salary"));
}

//adding item to ArrayList
public boolean addIncomeItem(item Item){
    Log.d(TAG, "addIncomeItem: addI");
    return IncomeItems.add(Item);
}

//getting ArrayList
public static ArrayList<item> getIncomeItems() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getIncomeItems: getI");
    return IncomeItems;
}
```

I set my ArrayList to the RecyclerView in the Main Activity

```
//Recycler View in Main Activity
RVAdapter IncomeAdapter = new RVAdapter(this);
Util util = new Util();
MainIncomeRV.setAdapter(IncomeAdapter);
MainIncomeRV.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));
IncomeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
IncomeAdapter.setItems(util.getIncomeItems());
```

In the 2nd Activity, I have a button to create a new item by getting data from the user.(I skipped some Widgets intitiation code here). At last I add the item to the ArrayList which set to the Recycler View in the Main Activity.

```
//Button in 2nd Activity
SubmitIncomeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Date = date_day.getSelectedItem().toString() +"-" + 
date_month.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + 
date_year.getSelectedItem().toString();
            id++;
            item IncomeItem = new item(id, 
 Integer.parseInt(Money.getText().toString()), Date, 
IncomeCategories.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
Description.getText().toString());
            util=new Util();
            util.addIncomeItem(IncomeItem);
            Toast.makeText(IncomePage.this, IncomeItem.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(IncomePage.this, 
String.valueOf(util.getIncomeItems().size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: addI");
        }
    });

}
```

No error occurred, but the item(IncomeItem) created in the 2nd Activity cannot be added to the Main Activity.

I expected the item will show in the Recycler view when I return to the Main Activity. Is it the problem that I use the return button to go back to the Main Activity?

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `IncomeItem item` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe, "item" is the Class name, "IncomeItem" is the Object that I was going to create, therefore I think  "item IncomeItem" should be correct.

Comment: How you going from secondActivity to mainActivity? By pressing back button or `submitIncomeBtn` is clicked?

Comment: I tried to press the back button, then I used the OnBackPressed() method to create another back button, both didn't work.   The submitIncomeBtn now is just used to add the item to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Following two points should work for you:

- You should use same **util** object which is used in MainActivity
  instead of creating new in submit button under 2nd Activity, So pass **util** object to
  2nd activity.
- Also pass adapter object to 2nd Activity, so that you can call NotifyDatasetChanged()
  function after adding item.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should work. First create an `arrayList` in your `2ndActivity`.

```
ArrayList<Item> str = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

In SubmitIncomeBtn,

```
SubmitIncomeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Date = date_day.getSelectedItem().toString() +"-" + date_month.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-" + date_year.getSelectedItem().toString();
            id++;
            item IncomeItem = new item(id,Integer.parseInt(Money.getText().toString()), Date, IncomeCategories.getSelectedItem().toString(),Description.getText().toString());
            str.add(IncomeItem) // add IncomeItem to arrayList
        }
    });
```

In 2ndActivity, you need to have this code to pass arrayList to MainActivity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("mylist", str);
    setResult(1, intent);
}
```

Finally in `MainActivity`, add this code to receive data from 2ndActivity

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           ArrayList<Item> myList = (ArrayList<Item>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
        }
    }
}
```